# Teradata sql Split undefined delimiter number

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table p

```
  id_people  age 
     1       22
     2                 --->   (empty)
     3      (10,20)
```

I want to get result like this

```
  id_people  age 
      1       22
      3       10
      3       20
```

I have tried this

```
    select t.id_people, 
    STRTOK(t.age,',',1) AS COL_1,STRTOK(t.age,',',2) AS COL_2 from 
(select id_people,age from p  where LENGTH(age) >0 ) t
```

First of all , it works but i still have the brackets. how can i delete brackets ? Second question : It works fine because i know i have only one comma in a row, if i didn't know the number of comma in a row for column age, i wouldn't be able to handle by this way.
 How can I use a kind of loop for a situation like that? 
Example :

```
 id_people    age 
   1        (17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,....)
   2        (30,31,32)
   3         -->    (empty)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides STRTOK there's also STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE :-)

The syntax is a bit unusual:

```
WITH cte (id_people, age) AS
 (
   SELECT id_people, age FROM dropme
 )
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE
 ( STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE( cte.id_people , cte.age, '(),') 
   RETURNS ( id_people INT , TokenNum INT , Token VARCHAR (10) CHARACTER SET UNICODE ) 
 ) dt
```

Comment: Can you explain the `(),` bit that you're passing the strtok_split_to_table function?  Is it treating each of those as a potential delimiter?

Comment: @Andrew: Yes, each of those characters is treated as a delimiter, this is mainly for tokenizing sentences into words.

Comment: Ok thank you very much. It works exactly as expected.